# extract date from data file in R

Tags: r, date, extract

Here is the text file:

```
1   Toy Story (1995)    01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%20(1995)   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   GoldenEye (1995)    01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?GoldenEye%20(1995) 0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
3   Four Rooms (1995)   01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Four%20Rooms%20(1995)  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
4   Get Shorty (1995)   01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Get%20Shorty%20(1995)  0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   Copycat (1995)  01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Copycat%20(1995)   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
6   Shanghai Triad (Yao a yao yao dao waipo qiao) (1995)    01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/Title?Yao+a+yao+yao+dao+waipo+qiao+(1995)    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   Twelve Monkeys (1995)   01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Twelve%20Monkeys%20(1995)  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
8   Babe (1995) 01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Babe%20(1995)  0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   Dead Man Walking (1995) 01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Dead%20Man%20Walking%20(1995)  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  Richard III (1995)  22-Jan-96   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Richard%20III%20(1995) 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
11  Seven (Se7en) (1995)    01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Se7en%20(1995) 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
12  "Usual Suspects, The (1995)"    14-Aug-95   "http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Usual%20Suspects,%20The%20(1995)" 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
13  Mighty Aphrodite (1995) 30-Oct-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Mighty%20Aphrodite%20(1995)    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
14  "Postino, Il (1994)"    01-Jan-94   "http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Postino,%20Il%20(1994)"   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
15  Mr. Holland's Opus (1995)   29-Jan-96   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Mr.%20Holland's%20Opus%20(1995)    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16  French Twist (Gazon maudit) (1995)  01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Gazon%20maudit%20(1995)    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
17  From Dusk Till Dawn (1996)  05-Feb-96   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?From%20Dusk%20Till%20Dawn%20(1996) 0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
18  "White Balloon, The (1995)" 01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Badkonake%20Sefid%20(1995) 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19  Antonia's Line (1995)   01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Antonia%20(1995)   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  Angels and Insects (1995)   01-Jan-95   http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Angels%20and%20Insects%20(1995)    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

I have used this code to import the data from the file:

```
Movies = read.table("Movies.txt", 
               sep="\t", 
               col.names=c( "MId", "title", "date", "link", "c1", "c2", "c3","c4",           "c5", "c6","c7", "c8", "c9","c10", "c11", "c12","c13", "c14", "c15","c16", "c17", "c18", "c19"),
               fill=FALSE, 
               strip.white=TRUE,
               quote = "")
```

How can I add a new column to "Movies" which contains "Year"

You can use the year (which is not tabbed out) or extract the year from the Date. Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I would use something like `library(lubridate); x <- dmy("01-Jan-96"); year(x)` or the `getYear`from `library(gdata)`

Comment: @ChristofKluß dmy function not found

Comment: you'll need some additional packages, you can install them with `install.packages(c("lubridate","gdata","stringr"))`

Comment: This works, however 01-Jan-45 becomes 2045 instead of 1945. How would I fix this. And thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
lines1 <- readLines('Movies.txt')
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_extract(lines1, perl('(?<=[(])\\d+')))
#[1] 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1994 1995
#[16] 1995 1996 1995 1995 1995
```

Or using `base R`

```
as.numeric(regmatches(lines1,regexpr('(?<=[(])\\d+', lines1, perl=TRUE)))
#[1] 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 1994 1995
#[16] 1995 1996 1995 1995 1995
```

Comment: @JohnDoe  Sorry, I didn't understand http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf  If you don't have that library, you can install it.